# How to close pyarrow connection to Dremio?

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow, dremio, apache-arrow-flight

I am using `pyarrow` to connect to the `Dremio` cloud and query the datasets.
Documentation - https://docs.dremio.com/cloud/client-applications/python/

My question is how can I close the connection to `Dremio` after I finish the job?

Comment: Isn't it a matter of closing the FlightClient? https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.flight.FlightClient.html#pyarrow.flight.FlightClient.close

Comment: This is the documentation I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You to call [FlichtClient.close](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.flight.FlightClient.html#pyarrow.flight.FlightClient.close)